# What is the name of this song in ep1 Hibike Euphonium 2

Tags: music, hibike-euphonium

Between 24:00 to 26:00, can someone telling me what is the song name?

[Hibike! Euphonium 2 Episode 1](http://www.crunchyroll.com/sound-euphonium/episode-1-mid-summer-fanfare-721567)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The song is Polovtsian Dances from the opera Prince Igor by Alexander Borodin.

Funny that the first [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TmfTqVqngO8) that hits on Google seems to also have attracted other fans of the anime as well.

Comment: thank you so much !!! I tried to find for sometimes but no hope until today !